# Connecting to remote server with hive

Tags: hive

So I have two machines, and I am trying to connect to the hive server with another machine. I simply enter

`$hive -h<IP> -p<PORT>`

However, it says I need to install hadoop. I only want to connect remotely. So why would I need hadoop? Is there any way to bypass this?

Answer (score 2):

The `hive` program depends on the `hadoop` program, because it works by reading from HDFS, launching map-reduce jobs, etc. (In Hive, unlike a typical database server, the command-line interface actually does all the query processing, translating it to the underlying implementation; so you don't usually really run a "Hive server" in the way you seem to be expecting.) This doesn't mean that you need to actually install a Hadoop cluster on this machine, but you will need to install the basic software to connect to your Hadoop cluster.

One way to bypass this is run the Hive JDBC/Thrift server on the box that has the Hadoop infrastructure — that is, to run the `hive` program with command-line options to run it as a Hive-server on the desired port and so on — and then connect to it using your favorite JDBC-supporting SQL client. This more closely approximates the sort of database-server model of typical DBMSes (though it still differs, in that it still leaves open the possibility of other `hive` connections that *aren't* through this server). (Note: this used to be a bit tricky to set up. I'm not sure if it's easier now than it used to be.)

And this is probably obvious, but for completeness: another way to bypass this restriction is to use `ssh`, and actually run `hive` on the box that has the Hadoop infrastructure. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Newer Hive CLI actually allows connecting to a remote Thrift server. See the beginning of https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli The remote machine should be running a Hive server for this to work.

You don't need your local box to be a part of a Hadoop cluster. However, you may need Hadoop programs/jars for Hive to work. If you install Hive from a standard repository, it should include a Hadoop distribution.